# Change perl for mod_perl

Tags: linux, perl, mod-perl

I've just installed a new version of perl on my linux webserver(upgrading from 5.10.1 to 5.12.4), and I'd hoped that everything will go smoothly but it seems that it didn't. The default perl version now in the system is the new one, but mod_perl is still stuck on the older version. My question is: can i just tell mod_perl to use the new version of perl, or do i have to reinstall it? From what i think there should be a way of just changing the interpreter and not reinstalling, but I wasn't able to find it yet.

Answer (score 3):

mod_perl needs to be built against whatever version of Perl it is using (it has the perl compiled wrapped up inside it). You will need to install a 5.12.4 version.

In the long term, you might want to considered moving off mod_perl and onto Plack/PSGI.

Comment: I have already installed perl 5.12.4, but do I need to recompile mod_perl also?

Comment: Yes, that is what the first paragraph of this answer says (twice).